# Python and XML: Update an attribute and write file problems

Tags: python, xml, setattribute

I'm trying to update an attribute on a child, then write that updated element to the document. I'm running into this error: 'AttributeError: Element instance has no attribute 'getiterator' '

I made this after piecing together a bunch of tutorials and resources, so let me know if anything else stands out (not too sure what I'm doing).  Thanks!

Here's what I have so far:

Inside the XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<notes>
    <prepData a_assetType="Geometry" b_assetSel="[u'pPyramid1', u'pTorus1']"/>
    <prepData a_assetType="Rig" b_assetSel="[u'pPyramid1']"/>
    <prepData a_assetType="Controls" b_assetSel="[u'pPyramid1']"/>
</notes>
```

Write XML code:

```
xml_file_path = "{0}/{1}_prepData.xml".format( info_dir, asset_type )
doc = ET.parse( xml_file_path )
dom = parse( xml_file_path )
root = doc.getroot()

nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName( 'prepData' )

match = []
for node in nodes:
    if node.attributes['a_assetType'].value == asset_type:
        match.append( node )

for node in match:
    node.setAttribute( "b_assetSel", str(asset_sel) )


out = ET.tostring( node )
dom = minidom.parseString( out )
xml_file = open("{0}/{1}_prepData.xml".format( info_dir, asset_name ), "w")
xml_file.write( dom.toprettyxml() )
xml_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `xml.etree.ElementTree` to search and set the element's attribute:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
root = doc.getroot()

for elm in root.findall(".//prepData[@a_assetType='%s']" % asset_type):
    elm.attrib["b_assetSel"] = str(asset_sel)

out = ET.tostring(root)
print(out)
```

Here we are using a simple [`XPath` expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) to find all `prepData` elements having the desired `a_assetType` attribute value. For each element found, we set the `b_assetSel` attribute value via the [`.attrib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib).

Comment: It worked! Great explaination too, thanks for taking the time :D